# Trigger a PHP function with AJAX then display the content on a DIV

Tags: php, html, ajax

So I have a function like this, it is not done yet:

```
function viewTestimonials(){

$sql=mysql_query("");

$msg="
    <table class=\"tftable\" border=\"1\">
        <tr><th>Testimonials</th></tr>
    ";

        while($ressult=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msg=$msg."
            <tr><td> </td></tr>
            <tr><td> </td></tr>
            ";
        }

$msg=$msg."
    </table>
    ";

    return $msg;
}
```

Then I have a link to call the function:

```
<a href="controls.php?control=viewTestimonial">View Testimonials</a>
```

so basically the page will reload and I have a condition like this to call my function:

```
if($_GET['control']=='viewTestimonial'){
$control=viewTestimonials();
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to call the function just using AJAX so the page don't need to reload to show the output into the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.

javascript: AJAX, like asked.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "some_page.php",
      type : 'POST',
      data : {control : 'hi'},
      datatype: 'json',
      success : function (resp){
          var resp = $.parseJSON(resp);
          // do stuff with resp
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
          console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
});
```

php

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: how about the type is GET and what should I put on data: {control: 'hi'), what is the **hi** for?

Comment: "hi" is just a random string. for you it would most likely be "viewTestimonial" and yes that should have been POST not GET. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

YES, there is a way using AJAX. But I recommend using JQuery [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

**Description:** Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

So your code should look like:

```
<html>  
<head>
<script>
function viewTestimonials(){

  $.post( "controls.php", {control: viewTestimonial}, function( data ) {
      $( "#div_name" ).html( data );
    });
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <a href='#' onclick='viewTestimonials()'>View Testimonials</a>
    </html>
```

You need to install JQuery. Instruction is here from w3schools which i think is correct: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: i tried this but it will execute even though i didn't click the link yet.

Comment: in the **$.post( "controls.php"** the controls.php i will change it with the php file where my functions are located?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it if your PHP file where your functions are has a different name

Comment: I tried it but i am getting this error

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply call the function from ajax, you can make a page which will run your function and you can call that page from ajax and display the output.

so in your page you can have ajax call something like this.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myID"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $.ajax({
       url: "getdata.php",
       context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
       $('#myID').html( data );
  });
</script>
```

and for the ajax call page getdata.php you can have something like.

```
$sql=mysql_query("");

$msg="
    <table class=\"tftable\" border=\"1\">
        <tr><th>Testimonials</th></tr>
    ";

        while($ressult=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msg=$msg."
            <tr><td> </td></tr>
            <tr><td> </td></tr>
            ";
        }

$msg=$msg."
    </table>
    ";

   echo $msg;
```

Comment: I want to use it for multiple links with different function to call, so how will I do it?